# How to achieve select and insert item as one transaction in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I am develping one application in which i am using AWS DynamoDB as database. but somewhere i am checking some conditions means selecting data from DynamoDB and check some conditions at java side and based on selected data i am inserting one item in DynamoDB table. I want selection and insertion of data as one transaction because if its not then i might get with two different items in a DynamoDB as it has to be one becuase java application running on multiple Ec2 instances. I am afraid of two simultaneous select requests. I am using Transaction API of dynamodb. Is there any suggestion? Or can it be implemented using DynamoDB Transaction API? I want to deploy java code on AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: See the following AWS blog article `Performing Conditional Writes Using the Amazon DynamoDB Transaction Library`: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/performing-conditional-writes-using-the-amazon-dynamodb-transaction-library/

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about atomicity of operations on individual items, use the UpdateItem API with condition expressions.